# Connected part of $S$-matrix generating functional

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, greens-functions, partition-function, s-matrix-theory

I am currently studying an article by A.Jevicki et. al. (https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.37.1485) and I am a little confused. They say that the generating functional of the $S$-matrix is related to the generating functional for the connected Green's functions as follows (formula (2) in the article)

$$S(\varphi)=[W(J)]|_{J(x)=\varphi(x)(\partial^2_{x}+m^2)}\tag{2}$$
Where $\varphi(x)$ is supposed to satisfy free field equation.

I know the reduction formula, but it connects the generating functional of $S$-matrix with generating functional of disconnected Green's functions $Z$. I can't figure out how to link these two expressions in any way. Because the generating functional $W$ is associated with $Z$ as

$$W=-i\ln Z,$$

cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram#Connected_diagrams:_linked-cluster_theorem) but i still can't get the first formula (2).